# Can't add Windows 10 weather tile to start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, tiles, weather

I don't know how, but I've made only one weather tile for specific place disappear and there's no option to pin it to start menu again.

What I can choose from is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw2Om.png) while others have [those](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpOa6.png). There's no tile for this location pinned at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution.

1. Uninstall Weather app through PowerShell by typing this:

   Get-AppxPackage *bingweather* | Remove-AppxPackage
2. Restart PC.
3. Go to Windows Store and install MSN Weather app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pin or repin an app then click or tap the “All apps” button, long-press or right-click the app you want, and select “Pin to Start”.

Comment: It's less like an app, it's more like a widget I want to pin. For example now I have Brussel, London and Warsaw pinned to see what's the weather in those cities, but I can't pin Moscow.

Comment: Ok, i got it, trying to find solution now.

Comment: As of now i can offer you to update/reinstall appropriate widget, or to try another one. Otherwise, you can wait for the updated version of it, or ask the question on MS support. Good luck!

Comment: Weather app is installed by default in W10. I've also thought about deleting all settings for Weather, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can ask coincident question, there are many craving for that users at this site.

Comment: I can confirm that selecting "Pin to Start Menu" will cause Weather to create a new tile in the Start Menu. You then have to right click on it, select "More" and then "Turn Live Tile on".